# Change text color based on view background color/gradient in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, colors

I have a view with a `RoundedRectangle` and a `Text`. The `RoundedRectangle` has a `background`, which is a `Color` or `AnyGradient`. Now, being this dynamic I need to change the `foregroundColor` of the text based on the color of the `background`. How can I achieve this result?
Below the `body` of my view.

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
            .fill(background)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
        Text(title)
    }
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use a variable or a function. There's no `getColor` method or anything like that to read the color of the rectangle once you've set it.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a computed property that returns the foreground color based on the gradient

```
var body: some View {
    let foregroundColor = background.isDark ? Color.white : Color.black
    
    return ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
            .fill(background)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
        Text(title)
            .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
    }
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
}
```

To see whether the colour is dark or light you can define a stuct that calculates the luminance.

```
extension Color {
    var isDark: Bool {
        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0
        guard UIColor(self).getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: nil) else {
            return false
        }
        
        let lum = 0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue
        return lum < 0.5
    }
}
```

Comment: My `background` could be a `Color` or `AnyGradient`. How can I get the "main" color from a gradient?

Comment: You'll need to extract the first color stop of the gradient then return the color. EG: extension AnyGradient {
    var mainColor: Color? {
        guard let firstColorStop = self.stops.first else {
            return nil
        }
        return firstColorStop.color
    }
}
If the gradient doesn't have a color stop or has no color the extension should return nil. @AndreaMarioLufino

Comment: That's nice, but `AnyGradient` does not have `stops` property. How can I extract the main color without it?